# Rails Error: Undefined method `add_product' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce

I'm quite new to Rails so might be a stupid mistake i'm making and just need someone to point it out.

Building a small shopping cart app. When i click 'Add to Cart', it throws up this error:

```
NoMethodError in LineItemsController#create
 undefined method `add_product' for nil:NilClass
```

Parameters:

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"uZ6zOfA237VBzt3Pz2tEBESzjv2pg+Vhx73DTolL8f76ANS80qiU6+wcN8Tvq/r+CSZvzxnkKll/ZJl2H2XePQ==",
 "product_id"=>"1"}
```

Here's the code:

line_items_controller

```
def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to customer_cart_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Cart Model:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user

def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
end

def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
end
end
```

Add to Cart Button:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The `@car` variable is `nil`, where is it defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
def create
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
```

line [3], uses `@cart`, but @cart was never set before it so it doesnt know what it is at that point.

So you need to set @cart before using it. Ex:

`@cart = Cart.find(params[:cart_id]`

Also, you will need to update the code:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
```

to (if your `cart` object exists here):

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product, cart_id: cart) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer  -  '<%=  render partial: "line_items/line_item", collection: (at)cart.line_items %>' - This line throws up an error in the view. The error is: 
undefined method 'line_items' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This means that the @ cart object is again not set. I assume that now, we are in the SHOW action in the controller or something like that. So, in the definition of that action in the controller, set the value of @ cart

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. You are right, but i have this in the show action  ||

class Customer::CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
   
    @ cart = if current_user
      current_user.cart
    else
      Cart.find session[:cart_id]
    end
  end
end

Comment: Please accept my answer if you find it corret. As for your comment, maybe it should be if current_user @ cart = current_user.cart else @ cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id]) end. Try that and see what happens. If is fails, maybe the current user has no cart set, or the session has no cart_id  set

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined your `@cart` instance variable and accessing its `add_product` method in your `LineItemsController`'s `create` method.

```
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)  # <== HERE
```

Comment: thought it was the 'add_product' that was nil?